# Обсчитать данные времени, php

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос, как мне от текущего времени отнять время из бд? У меня есть табличка с типом `Time`, там пока около 20 записей, мне нужно обсчитать, через сколько времени будет `время`, которое записано в этой ячейке?

Например: Автобус отправляется в 12:43:00. Мне нужно узнать через какое время он отправиться(типа отправляется через 3:12:00). Все это дело нужно сделать на php

Comment: все это дело надо сделать не на пхп, а в sql-запросе, а вот результат уже вывести на пхп. чтобы это сделать в запросе, следует ознакомится с функциями для работы с датой-временем той СУБД, которую вы используете

Comment: @teran Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как это осуществить? Я примерно придумал формулу, но она работает только тогда, когда на часах от 12 до 24
```
ADDTIME(SUBTIME('24:00:00', CURTIME()), nameTime)
```
типа так как-то

Comment: Посмотрите реализацию любого временного таймера. Это не обязательно через запрос базы делать, ибо вам может захотеться потом сделать к примеру отсчет в реальном времени.

Comment: В MySQL следует использовать функцию [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: *но если сейчас 12 часов дня, то так уже не проканает* А это целиком и полностью Ваша вина. Автобус отправляется не в 5 утра, а в 5 утра вполне определённого дня. И сейчас 12 часов тоже вполне определённого дня. Однако информацию о дате Вы похерили - и при этом рассчитываете получить верный результат? а вот фигушки. PS. Кстати, без дат результат Вы получите тоже правильный - минус пять часов означает "автобус ушёл 5 часов назад".

Comment: @Akina Я полагал что это продумано, как с датами, например. Хорошо, как мне тогда исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Тип time это ни что иное как значение в секундах, если вы знаете конечное значение, то можно к примеру так: strtotime(время отправления автобуса)-время из таблицы, ну а после вы получите значение в секундах которое проблемы перевести в нужное Вам значение я думаю не возникнет

Comment: *как мне тогда исправить ситуацию?* Конвертировать в секунды, поделить на количество секунд в сутках, и взять остаток от деления - он по определению положителен.

Comment: @Akina Что-то у меня не получается. 
функция перевода в секунды
function second ($time) {
   $part = explode(':', $time); //Разбиваем на подстроки
   $a=$part[0]*3600+$part[1]*60+$part[2]; //$part[0]-это часы, $part[1]-минуты и на всякий случай $part[2]-секунды.
   return $a;
}
Перевод в нормальное время
function normalTime($tt) {
 $tim = gmdate("H:i:s", $tt);
 return $tim;
}
и вот
date_default_timezone_set('Ukraine/Kiev');
$date = date('h:i:s', time());
$time1 = second($myrow['nameTime']);
$time2 = second($date);
$time = ($time1 % $time2);
$normtime = normalTime($time);

Comment: @Akina Выводит оно время отправки. Не могу понять, что я не так сделал

Comment: Вы пропустили важную фразу: *все это дело надо сделать не на пхп, а в sql-запросе*.

Comment: @Akina вот, итог тот же, выводит время отправки. Поправьте, где не прав
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(nameTime)%TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME())), TIME_TO_SEC(nameTime)%TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME()), TIME_TO_SEC(nameTime), TIME_TO_SEC(CURTIME()), CURTIME(), nameTime, nameBus, namePrice FROM (ttime JOIN time_flight USING (id_time)) JOIN flight USING (id_flight) INNER JOIN bus AS b ON b.id_bus = flight.id_bus INNER JOIN price AS p ON p.id_price = flight.id_price ORDER BY nameTime

Comment: В показанном коде как-то в принципе отсутствует функция TIMEDIFF(). И константу количества секунд в сутках (86400, если что) я тоже не вижу...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда через strtotime

```
$todate = strtotime("now");
//$fromdate = $bus->getStartDateTime()->format('M d, Y H:i:s');
$fromdate = strtotime('03 June 2019 13:00:00 +3 GMT');
$calculate_seconds = $fromdate - $todate;
$days = floor($calculate_seconds / (24 * 60 * 60)); // convert to days
$timeInDays = $days * (24 * 60 * 60);
$hours = floor(($calculate_seconds - $timeInDays) / (60 * 60)); // convert to hours
$timeInHours = $hours * (60 * 60);
$min = floor(($calculate_seconds - $timeInDays - $timeInHours) / 60); // convert to min
echo($days . ' d. ' . $hours . ' h. ' . $min . ' m.');
```

Comment: Вытаскиваешь нужную дату из базы и вставляешь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через js. Просто передаешь полученное из БД значение в любой в нужный элемент и на выходи получишь результат с пересчетом в 1 сек. Грубо говоря таймер

```
<div id="countdown-timer"
 data-time="<?php echo $bus->getStartDateTime()->format('M d, Y H:i:s'); ?>" >
```

```
var countdownTimer = $("#countdown-timer"),
        countDownDate = new Date(countdownTimer.data('time')).getTime();

    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
            hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
            minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
            seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        var remainingTime;

        var formatTime = function (count, label) {
            return "<span>" + count + "</span> <sub>" + _t(label) + ".</sub>"
        }

        if (days > 0) {
            remainingTime = formatTime(days, 'd') + ' ' + formatTime(hours, 'h') + ' ' + formatTime(minutes, 'm');
        } else if (days === 0 && hours !== 0 && minutes !== 0) {
            remainingTime = formatTime(hours, 'h') + ' ' + formatTime(minutes, 'm') + ' ' + formatTime(seconds, 's');
        } else if (days === 0 && hours === 0 && minutes !== 0) {
            remainingTime = formatTime(minutes, 'm') + ' ' + formatTime(seconds, 's');
        } else if (days === 0 && hours === 0 && minutes === 0) {
            remainingTime = formatTime(seconds, 's');
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            remainingTime = '<div class=\"countdown-timer\">' + formatTime(0, 'h') + ' ' + formatTime(0, 'm') + '</div>';
        }

        $('#countdown-timer').html(function() {
            $('#countdown-timer span.nbsp').remove();
            return remainingTime;
        });

    }, 1000);
```

Если времени больше суток - 1 d. 12 h. 15 m. 
Менее суток - 16 h. 45 m. 15 s.

Comment: Стыдно как-то говорить, но у меня не работает js код. Не конкретно ваш, а вообще. Как-то был один проект, то там он четко все грузил. А начал новый, и тут 0 на массу